# Is there a way to get all combinations of overlap between values in dictionary, or from within a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, overlap, venn

I have a few lists

```
A =['D','KIT','SAP'],
B= ['F','G','LUFT','SAP'],
C= ['I','SAP'],
D= ['SAP','LUF','KIT'],
F= ['SAP','LUF','KIT','HASS']
```

I passed them in combinations to a dictionary. For example, I joined lists A and B as a key 'AB' in my new dictionary and appended the values from both lists like the list of values to that key 'AB'.

```
my_dict={"AB":[['D','KIT','SAP'],['F','G','LUFT','SAP']]}
```

My aim to get the overlap between the lists in multiple combination. For that, I could get with the following one liner.

```
   for k,v in my_dict.items():
        print(k,list(set.intersection(*[set(x) for x in v])))
```

AB ['SAP']

However, the problem here is that when I have more lists and more combinations it is tedious to define manually a dictionary with all possible combinations.

The aim is to achieve all possible combinations of lists. From the above-mentioned example, I have the following combination of lists. In this case that would be 5*5 +1 = 26 combinations. **And in the end, I would like to get the overlap for each of the following combinations.**

```
   AB, AC, AD, AF
    ABC, ABD, ABF
    ABCD, ABCDF
    ABCDF
BC, BD, BF
DF, DC
FC
```

The question is how could I achieve that in a pythonic way. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

As a side note, I do not want a dictionary in between if this combination of overlap is possible from the lists itself.

Thanks

Comment: That list doesn't contain all combinations. What about `BC, BD..` ETC?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just updated the question with all possible combinations. thanks for pointing that ou!

Comment: Just to make sure; you have a list of lists, and you want the items that appears in both list? I.e for `DF` you would have `['SAP','LUF','KIT'] ` returned, since it's the items appearing in `D` and `F`

Comment: Yes, but in combinations. Not just a list of lists and get one overlap.  In the end I need to get overlap for each combinations I mentioned in the question

Comment: But is the question regarding creating the combinations or getting the overlapped items? And what when you have 3 lists like `[["foo","bar","baz"],["foo"],["foo","qux","dal"]]` should that be `["foo","bar"]` (since it appears in more than 1) or only `"foo"` since it appears in all?

Comment: Getting the overlaps from all combinations. That is my question to be precise. Meaning that, I need the output for,
AB, AC, AD, AF
    ABC, ABD, ABF
    ABCD, ABCDF
    ABCDF
BC, BD, BF
DF, DC
FC

Comment: Yes, but is it *only* items that appears in *all* lists in a combination, or just items that overlap in some lists? say `A=["foo","bar","baz"]`,`B = ["foo","qux"]`, `C=["dal","bar"]` is `ABC` then returning `["foo"]` (it is in all of them) or `["foo","bar"]` (`bar` is in `A` and `C` i.e an overlap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all solutions. Each solution was helpful. However, none of them was the exact answer I was looking for. Nonetheless, all of them partly helped me to come up with the right solution. Posting for everyone might be helpful.

I first needed to create 26 combinations for 5 lists.
The initial lists

```
A =['D','KIT','SAP']
B= ['F','G','LUFT','SAP']
C= ['I','SAP']
D= ['SAP','LUF','KIT']
E= ['SAP','LUF','KIT','HASS']
```

Made a list of lists

```
lists = [A, B, C, D, E]
```

Defined empty list called combination as @marco's solution. And added all possible combinations based on the length of lists, plus one. The combinations are the values from our final dictionary.

```
 combinations =[]
    for l in range(2, len(lists) + 1):
        combinations += itertools.combinations(lists, l)
```

After that define a dictionary with keys and values from the list of the list. From here I adopted partly @butterflyknife's solution.

```
master_dict = dict(A=A, B=B, C=C, D=D, F=F)
```

For the keys of our final dictionary, we defined an empty list first. Then populated the combinations by using join.

```
key_list    = []
for i in range(2,len(master_dict) +1):
    for combo in it.combinations(master_dict.keys(), i):
        new_key = "".join(combo)
        if (len(combo)>1):
            key_list.append(new_key)
```

Now, with both keys and values. We populate our final dictionary.

```
final_dict = dict()
for key, elem in zip(key_list, combinations):
    final_dict[key] = list(elem)
```

This part is to find the overlaps and convert them to a data frame.

```
overlap_list  = []
dfs = []
for k,v in final_dict.items():
    overlap = list(set.intersection(*[set(x) for x in v]))
    overlap_list.append(overlap)
     #print(overlap, sep=", ")
    dct  ={ 'overlap':overlap,'number of overlapps':len(overlap),
              'overlap models':k}
    dfs.append(dct)
df          = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dfs)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at `itertools.combinations`. It returns all possible combinations of a given length for a given iterable. You'll have to loop over all possible lengths.

```
import itertools

lists = [A, B, C, D, E, F]

combinations = []

for l in range(2, len(lists) + 1):
    combinations += itertools.combinations(lists, l)
```

`combinations` will be a list of tuples with all possible combinations of at least two lists.

Answer (score 1):

[Edited solution after exchange in comments]

```
import itertools as it

A =['D','KIT','SAP'],
B= ['F','G','LUFT','SAP'],
C= ['I','SAP'],
D= ['SAP','LUF','KIT'],
F= ['SAP','LUF','KIT','HASS']

master_dict = dict(A=A, B=B, C=C, D=D, F=F)
for i in range(len(master_dict)):
    for combo in it.combinations(master_dict.keys(), i):
        new_key = "".join(combo)
        print(combo)
        if (len(combo)>1):
            mixed_dict[new_key] = set.intersection(*[set(master_dict[c][0]) for c in combo])
            print("---->" + str(mixed_dict[new_key]))
```

... with a couple of commented out print statements to show you what's going on. At the end of the script, you have a `new_dict` which looks like this:

[image]

I didn't add the combinations of length 1 on purpose, but you can remove the `if()` condition above to get them back.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The reason to use the magic keys is that wanted to know from does the overlap is coming. Meaning, if the overlap is from all lists I know it is from ABCDF. however, if the overlap is only between AB. There, I need a key indicator, telling me from which lists I am getting this overlapped list. Additionally, it is a scalable solution when you have multiple lists.

Comment: The solution is not generating the overlaps as well as the combinations correctly. For an input of 5 lists. One would expect 5*5 +1 combinations. Total 26 combinations. The current combination of output is larger than that.

Comment: I don't think you're counting the combinations correctly. For example, you don't have ACD in your list.

Comment: Thanks, yes, it is not in the question. You are right. The point is that we need 26 combinations. Which I think is not there in your solution. There is only 25 combination.  For example, ABCDF is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the dictionary creation with the answer of @Marco Breemhaar implemented, and I used his solution to create a dictionary as you wanted. Here is the code:

```
import itertools

import string
alphabet_string = string.ascii_uppercase
alphabet_list = list(alphabet_string)


A =['D','KIT','SAP']
B= ['F','G','LUFT','SAP']
C= ['I','SAP']
D= ['SAP','LUF','KIT']
E= ['SAP','LUF','KIT','HASS']

lists = [A, B, C, D, E]

combinations = []

for l in range(2, len(lists) + 1):
    combinations += itertools.combinations(lists, l)

alp_comb = []
for l in range(2, len(alphabet_list) + 1):
    alp_comb += itertools.combinations(alphabet_list[:len(lists)], l)

key_list = []
for alp_elem in alp_comb:
    key_name = ""
    for elem in alp_elem:
        key_name += elem
    key_list.append(key_name)
    key_name = None


res_dict = dict()
for key, elem in zip(key_list, combinations):
    res_dict[key] = list(elem)
print(res_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

To start solving the problem, I would turn the lists given to you into a dictionary. This is to easily reference the name of the list and the value with it.

Like what sagi commented, the combinations you listed does not give all combinations. So, I used the package itertools and the code from, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031/5131550, to get all possible combinations and slightly modified it to only give the results that are greater than one list long.

Then we need to add these to my_dict. I used a code snippet from geeksforgeeks, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-convert-a-tuple-to-a-string/, to turn the tuple into a string that we use as a key for my_dict. At the same time we are building a list to add to those afformentioned keys.

Then we just use your function to find the interlapping elements. We should expect there are 2^(len(listsdict)) - len(listsdict) - 1, because we exclude no elements and only one element. Hope this solves it.

```
from itertools import combinations

#turn list into a dictionary of lists
listsdict = {
    'A' : ['D','KIT','SAP'],
    'B' : ['F','G','LUFT','SAP'],
    'C' : ['I','SAP'],
    'D' : ['SAP','LUF','KIT'],
    'F' : ['SAP','LUF','KIT','HASS']
}

my_dict = {}

#from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-convert-a-tuple-to-a-string/
def convertTuple(tup):
    str = ''
    list = []
    for item in tup:
        str = str + item
        list += [listsdict[item]]
    my_dict[str] = list
    return str

#from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031/5131550
for L in range(0, len(listsdict)+1):
    for subset in combinations(listsdict, L):
        if len(subset) > 1:
            convertTuple(subset)

#OP's functions
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    print(list(set.intersection(*[set(x) for x in v])))
```

Comment: I get this error, at from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031/5131550
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable